# Problem in computing SerialversionUID from the command prompt

Tags: java

Whenever I am trying to compute serialversionUID from the command prompt, I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest".

classpath is set correctly.I have j2ee.jar in my classpath.

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Please paste the command and the $classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You only really need to do this if you have already-serialized instances of the class and you've changed it and want to maintain serialization-compatibility with the existing serializations. Otherwise just use 1L or -1L.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the JAR file containing javax.servlet.* is in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: i have j2ee.jar which contains javax.servlet.* in my classpath